# Private network bootnode(s)

Tags: go-ethereum, bootnodes

I am running a private PoA network and am wondering if I should make the first node a bootnode or just use static-nodes or trusted-nodes instead?

Is there any benefit to having a bootnode in a consortium or is it simply unnecessary?